# Interchange of integral and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, calculus-of-variations

Can anyone please suggest how to justify widely used formula for interchange of integral and infimum:

$
\inf_{u(t)\in U}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}g(t,u(t))dt=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\inf_{u\in U}g(t,u)dt,
$

where $ U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set and the function $g$ is Caratheodory?
In a Theorem by R. Tyrell Rockafellar the infimum on the right-hand side is taken over all $ u\in\mathbb{R}^n$:

$ 
\inf_{x\in X}\int_{S} f(s,x(s))\mu(ds)=\int_{S} \inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}f(s,x)\mu(ds),
$

where $ X $ is a decomposable linear space of measurable functions, and $ f$ is a normal integrand on $S\times \mathbb{R}^n$.

A possible workaround could be redefining the $ g$ function to be infinite for $ u\notin U$ and all $ t$. But I'm not sure if the Rockafellar theorem assumptions on normal integrand will be satisfied in this case?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Clearly there is an inequality.  So the problem becomes: for each $t$, choose $u(t)$ so that $g(t,u(t))$ is close to the infimum.  And make the choice so that $u(t)$ is measurable.  This may be known as a "measurable selection" theorem.

Comment: Hi can someone post a reference to this specific theorem of Rockafellar, I cant seem to find one.  Thanks.

Comment: @AIM_BLB I think is this one https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr073-IntegralFnlsNormalIntegrands.pdf